# Why is this string being overwritten instead of being concatenated?

Tags: c++

I'm just writing a little script to create some fake discord names.

To do this, I took a couple of .csv files with adjectives and nouns, imported them into vectors, and concatenated them. Ex:

```
vector<string> noun;
vector<string> adj;
infile.open("english-adjectives.txt");

  while(infile.good()){
    getline(infile,x);
    adj.push_back(x);
  }

  infile.close();

  shuffle(begin(adj), end(adj), rng);
```

I did the same thing for nouns, and then tried to concatenate them with a number, but I got a really weird result.

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < adj.size(); i++){
    string temp;
    temp.append(adj[i]);
    temp.append(noun[i]);
    discord.push_back(temp);
  }

  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < discord.size(); i++){
    cout << discord[i]  << "#0001" << "\n";
  }
```

output:

```
#0001icresearch
#0001downstairs
#0001edfiddle
```

When I remove the "#0001" part, it prints just fine.

```
honoredfiddle
wanderby
deliciousofficial
```

Any ideas on why this is happening? I checked the newline chars in all my .csv files, and it's formatted for Unix, so I have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: Unrelated danger: `while(infile.good()){ getline(infile,x); adj.push_back(x); }` Test for valid stream, read from stream, store in container regardless of whether or not read from stream succeeded. You need to read, then test, not test then read. `while(getline(infile,x)) { adj.push_back(x); }`

Comment: Your CSV file was made on Windows and has Windows line endings (`\r\n`).  But the computer you are running this on uses UNIX style line endings (`\n`) so each line in the CSV has a `\r` at the end that is not being removed as your program reads it.  A `\r` moves the cursor to the left edge of the current line, so the number overwrites the name. There are multiple ways of removing the `\r` from the CSV file - or you could even do it inside this program after reading the data.  One possible way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528995/remove-r-from-a-string-in-c

Comment: I also see no evidence `noun` has the identical number of elements as `adj`, which is a gaping hole in this methodology. if there are *fewer* adjectives than nouns, it will "work". If there are more, this is a recipe for undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Answer from [Jerry Jeremiah's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71027215/why-is-this-string-being-overwritten-instead-of-being-concatenated#comment125559535_71027215)

> Your CSV file was made on Windows and has Windows line endings. But
> yhe computer you are running this on uses UNIX style line endings so
> each line in the CSV has a \r at the end that is not being removed.
> There are multiple ways of removing the \r from the CSV file - or you
> could even do it inside this program after reading the data.

Took it into notepad++, edited the newlines to be just LF, and that fixed it.